# rake, Could not find rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake, debian, redmine

first of all I'm really not really friendly with ruby or with rails, so I got few issue when i try to install redmine.

In fact i have to type a rake commande :

```
rake generate_session_store
```

And server answers me :

```
"Could not find rails (=2.3.14) amongst [actionmail-2.3.11, actionmailer-2.3.5, actionpack..."
```

So i checked my rails version and i see that I got 2.3.11, I update it with gem, retry rake but the same error happends, I check again my rails version.

Suprise ! It's still 2.3.11.

I'm running on debian 6 with ruby 1.8.7, gem 1.8.19

What should i do ? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this ?

```
 gem install rails -v 2.3.14
```

Comment: it works but new probleme : "Please install RDoc 2.4.2+ to generate documentation"

Comment: try- `gem install rdoc -v 2.4.2`

Comment: same solution perhaps : gem install rdoc -v 2.4.2 ?

Comment: also, if you dont want the docs (it takes long to install them) you can always go gem install <yourgem> --no-rdoc --no-ri